# Haskell IO reverse string input

Tags: haskell, dictionary, io, sequence

I keep getting an error: couldn't match expected type 'Bool' with actual type '[t0]'. I'm trying to get user inputs of string and then output however many strings in reversed ORDER.

Example input:

```
HI1
HI2
```

Example output:

```
HI2
HI1
```

My code:

```
    Back :: Int -> IO()
    Back x = do line <- sequence_[getLine|[1..x]]
                     mapM_ print (reverse line)
```

Comment: Do you want the inputs and outputs to occur one on each line, or all the inputs in a single line, and all the outputs in a single line?

Comment: Take a look at [replicateM](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM).

Answer (score 8):

To expand on Vitus's comment, `import Control.Monad`, then

```
back count = do
    lines <- replicateM count getLine
    mapM_ putStrLn (reverse lines)
```

If this doesn't work for you, please say what error message you get, or give an example of incorrect output.

In this case, we can forego do notation fairly easily:

```
back count = mapM_ putStrLn . reverse =<< replicateM count getLine
```

Or

```
back count = mapM_ putStrLn =<< liftM reverse (replicateM count getLine)
```

You may or may not find either of those to be clearer.

---

Note that your function name must start with a lower case letter, e.g. `back`. `Back` as a function name is a syntax error.

Also note that indentation is significant. The indentation of the do block in your question is wrong; the do blocks in my and melpomene's answers are correctly indented.

Answer (score 3):

```
back :: Int -> IO ()
back x = do line <- sequence [getLine | _ <- [1 .. x]]
            mapM_ putStrLn (reverse line)
```

Comment: @user **I just remotely connected to your computer, so I could see the error message, but I won't tell anybody.**

Comment: @user What Ingo wants to tell you is that "it doesn't work" does not help us at all to give you a better answer. If you want a good answer, help us help you by providing more information than that. How is this solution wrong? It works fine for me, but maybe I have a different interpretation of what the program should do than you, in which case you should specify the program more precisely. Or maybe provide a case of input and output, where the program differs from what you want.